# Select rows with distinct domains

Tags: mysql, parsing, domain-name

So I have a Table that has a column called *href*

**href** contains URLs that have the same domain-name repeating many times

for example

http://www.google.com/blog

http://www.google.com/contact

http://www.google.com/dashboard/details/id/5

http://yahoo.com/user/login

http://www.yahoo.com/something/something

Notice google.com and yahoo.com domain name has appeared more than once. Now I want to write a query that would only get the distinct domain names. Running the query would result in only 2 rows the example above

google.com

yahoo.com

I am trying to use SUBSTRING_INDEX but not having much luck. I am not sure how to use it.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Comment: This answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1231230/30225 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to find the domain names including the subdomains

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( REPLACE( REPLACE( href,  'www.',  '' ) ,  'http://',  '' ) ,  '/', 1 ) AS domain_name
FROM  `cfk_linkdata` 
GROUP BY domain_name
ORDER BY domain_name ASC
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT (SUBSTRING_INDEX( REPLACE( REPLACE( href,  'www.',  '' ) ,  'http://',  '' ) ,  '/', 1 )) AS domain_name
FROM  `cfk_linkdata` 
ORDER BY domain_name ASC
```

Here is how to only get the domains (without the subdomains)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( href,  '/', 3 ) ,  '/', -1 ) ,  '.', -2 ) AS domain_name
FROM cfk_linkdata
GROUP BY domain_name
ORDER BY domain_name ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(href, 'www.', ''), '/', 3), 'http://', '')) AS domain
FROM urls
```

HTH

Edit: Removing subdomians

```
SELECT  DISTINCT(
        REPLACE(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(href, '/', 3), 
            '.', -2), 
        'http://', '')
    )
FROM urls
```

Comment: Thanks! I want to further slim it down just to the domain name e.g google.com . e.g maps.google.com/user/id/2. I want to extract just the domain google.comf

Answer (score 0):

If all of your URLs contain the protocol (http / https), then the domain will be the part before the 3rd /, so you can do

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(href, '/', 3) FROM table;
```

If you also want to strip the protocol:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(href, '/', 3), '/', -1) FROM table;
```

Comment: The second statement works but it also includes the subdomain. How can I get rig of the subdomain. e.g maps.google.com/user/id/2. I want to extract just the domain google.com